# How to change value of variable inside sum() function?

Tags: python

```
i=1
if int(n)==sum(int(x)**i for x in str(n); i=i+1)
   print("Disarum Number")
else:
   print("Non-Disarum Number")
```

I expected the value of i to increase after each iteration. I wanted a short version of the following code:

```
i=1
s=0
for x in str(n):
  s=s+(int(x)**i)
  i=i+1
```

Comment: You set i to 1 in the first line and never increase it, so it's fixed. The syntax of your for loop (i=i+1) is incorrect in Python,

Comment: `sum(int(x)**i for i, x in enumerate(str(n), 1))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, compound for is not a short version of a for loop.

It is an expression, not an instruction (even tho, in python, like in C, difference is less important, it still is).
I've recently explained that quite lengthly in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74008007/why-no-colon-in-forming-a-list-from-loop-in-one-line-in-python/74014840#74014840) to a different question (not at all a duplicate question. Just answer is pertinent here too), if you wish to read more about that. Bottom line being, you can only have a value in compound for. It is not "for thing in iterable, do something", but "worth something for thing in iterable".

So you can't add a print, or a i+=1 or an instruction in this.

The good news is that expression can still have side effects. And there is one expression, made from operator `:=` that has the side effect you want. It is both an expression (it has a value) and an instruction (it does something).

`i:=12` has the value 12, and has the side effect that, now, `i` value is 12. You can
`print(i:=12)`, and it prints value 12, which is value of expression `i:=12`, and sets `i` to be `12`. So it is somehow the equivalent of `i=12; print(i)`.

So in your case

```py
i=1
print(sum(int(x)**i for x in str(n); i=i+1))
```

has no meaning
But

```py
i=0
print(sum(int(x)**(i:=i+1) for x in str(n)))
```

has.
(Note that I initialize i to 0, not 1, because `i:=i+1` worth what was `i+1`, not `i`. So `i=0; print(i:=i+1)` prints 1, and set i to 1. First i in your iteration is 1, as wanted.

For example

```py
n=432
i=0
print(sum(int(x)**(i:=i+1) for x in str(n)))
```

Displays 21. That is 4¹+3²+2³=4+9+8=21. As expected I think.

So, your complete code turns

```py
i=0
if int(n)==sum(int(x)**(i:=i+1) for x in str(n))
   print("Disarum Number")
else:
   print("Non-Disarum Number")
```

Comment: Thanks mate for your time and help. I got my mistake and learnt something new.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (enumerate(iterable)) attaches indexes to the iterable).

```
if int(n)==sum(int(x)**i for i,x in enumerate(str(n),1)):
   print("Disarum Number")
else:
   print("Non-Disarum Number")
```

Another way to do this would be to loop on the INDEX i, and retrieve the digit with str(n)[i] :

```
if int(n) == sum( int(str(n)[i])**(i+1) for i in range(len(str(n)))):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do this as a function form named *disarium_number* :

```py
def disarium_number(number):
    number=str(number)
    sum_powers=0
    for i in [*number]:
        sum_powers=sum_powers+(int(i)**(number.index(i)+1))

    if int(sum_powers)==int(number):
        print("Disarium Number")
    else:
        print("Non-Disarium Number")
```

*Let's give it a try*:

```py
>>> disarium_number(175)
'Disarium Number'

>>> disarium_number(225)
'Non-Disarium Number'
```